# i18next backendConnector: loading namespace translations for language fr failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next

I want to fetch the translations from our translation microservice so I'm using the `i18next-http-backend` library.

So far I'm just looking to test what kind of object I need to pass to the callback inside the request parameter but I keep coming up with the error: `i18next::backendConnector: loading namespace translations for language fr failed', { test: 'Blah' }`

Currently my code is the following. Does anyone know why it is failing?

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';

i18n.use(Backend)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        backend: {
            crossDomain: false,
            withCredentials: false,
            overrideMimeType: false,
            requestOptions: {
                // used for fetch, can also be a function (payload) => ({ method: 'GET' })
                mode: 'cors',
                credentials: 'same-origin',
                cache: 'default'
            },
            request: function(
                options,
                url,
                callback,
                payload
            ) {
                callback(
                    { test: 'Blah' },
                    {
                        status: 200
                    }
                );
            },
            reloadInterval: false
        },
        lng: 'fr',
        fallbackLng: false,
        debug: true,
        ns: ['translations'],
        defaultNS: 'translations',
        react: {
            useSuspense: false,
            wait: true
        },
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false
        }
    });

export default i18n;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> 'callback' is a function that takes two parameters, 'err' and 'res'.
> 'err' should be an error
> 'res' should be an object with a 'status' property and a 'data' property
> containing a stringified object instance beeing the key:value
> translation pairs for the requested language and
> namespace, or null in case of an error.

You are missing the first parameter ('err'):

```
callback(null, {...});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring a defaultNS:

```
ns: ['common'],
defaultNS: 'common'
```